# Delete a docker image with a child image

Tags: docker, dependencies

I'am trying to delete a docker image that has a child image,
and docker says that it can't be deleted because it has a child.
(Error message: unable to delete  (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images)

My questions are:

1. In what situation this kind of 'child-parent dependency' is produced?
2. How can I remove this 'dependency', so that I can treat each image freely?

---

Below is the actual situation when I tried to remove the parent image:

In my case, the parent image was untagged.

Since some articles say

"Use 'docker rmi ' instead of 'docker rmi '",

so I tagged my parent image with any name(for example test:test)
and then tried to delete by 'docker rmi test:test',
but the image was just untagged again,
and not removed from the image list (shown by 'docker image ls -a')

---

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you finding the "parent" and "child" images?  I wouldn't expect you to get this error trying to delete an image by name – `docker rmi parent` should be able to remove the name but leave the layer content behind – but if you are getting the error using a hex image ID, a parent image without a tag wouldn't normally be included in `docker images` output.